# React Native: press tab with Detox

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, detox, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm writing automation test with Detox for my react native app. 
Main screen of my app has a TabNavigator component.

How can I reach some specific tab in Detox test?
Can I set testID for tabs in TabNavigator?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you find out dude ? Same problem here

Comment: Actually I used `by.text()` matcher to reach my tab.

Answer (score 1):

in your navigationOptions add `tabBarTestID: 'Tab element'` property and call `await element(by.id('Tab element')).tap();`